# css selector for text after checked input

Tags: css

I am trying make the text after input bold if input is checked but I am failing. I think my is not finding the text. I appreciate any help or hint.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+ {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label for="radio-foobar">
  <input type="radio" id="radio-3" value="3" />
  Hello world!
</label>
```

Comment: wrap the text inside a span

Comment: as far as i know you cant select parent label with css. You will have to use js

Comment: i dont know why this question was closed. This question is about radio with parent label not about radio then label situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`focus-within` and a transition hack can approximate this. The transition is to make sure the style is kept even if you click outside.

```css
label {
  font-weight: 400;
  transition:0s 999s;
}

label:focus-within {
  font-weight: 900;
  transition:0s;
}
```

```html
<label for="radio-3">
  <input type="radio" id="radio-3" value="3" >
  Hello world!
</label>
```

Comment: I can use scss. Is there a cleaner solution using scss?

Comment: But this doesnt work on clicking the text right? usually radio button will be checked even if we click on the text. Just curious to know :)

Comment: @Node.JS the cleaner solution is to change the HTML structure

Comment: @HemaNandagopal it does work, the for attribute wasn't correct

Answer (score 1):

On html, it is needed to cover `Hello World!` into html tag like `<span>` and on CSS you can select that span next to `checked` input using `+` CSS selector.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label for="radio-foobar">
  <input type="radio" id="radio-3" value="3" />
  <span>Hello world!</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I cannot change the structure and add a `span`

Comment: Can you add label instead of span?

Comment: I cannot change the structure

Comment: Without changing the structure, it is impossible to change the parent style when child is checked. You need to use javascript for this.